# irrecognizable codes by running R script in Mac Terminal

Tags: r

I was running an R script through mac terminal and the log file shows many irrecognizable codes at the end and no results were returned then. Does anybody know what's the likely reasons.
[image]

Comment: Looks like the characters shown when you access a binary file with vi. Maybe your script is producing a plot and got included in the log file?

Comment: Thanks @ddiez. It seems helpful and I will check back.

Comment: I'm voting to send this to superuser.com, which has commonly used tags called osx and terminal. You might want to check those out. http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac+terminal